# Examples from angularjs.org are not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying examples from [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org) page. It seems that two last examples are not working for me: 
*Wire up a Backend* only shows 'JavaScript Projects' label in my browser and
*Create Components* shows this on the page:

```
    Localization
    Pluralization

Date: Sunday, April 1, 2012
Currency: $123,456.00
Number: 98,765.432
no beers
1 beer
2 beers
3 beers
4 beers
5 beers
6 beers
```

Two first examples are working as expected. Am I missed something?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 31.0.1650.34. Can you check your javascript console?

Comment: In FF console I have this: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$injector/modulerr?

Comment: And in Chrome console: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=project&p1=Error%3A…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A29%3A42)